# MySQL load command: is there a wildcard available for the datafile?

Tags: mysql, wildcard, load-data-infile

I have the following file dumped daily into one of our online directories:

```
dat-part2-489359-43535-toward.txt
```

The numbers change each day randomly.

I have the following code to try and LOAD the file:

```
mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'dat-part2-%-toward.txt' 
          REPLACE INTO TABLE my_table
          FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY ''
          LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
          IGNORE 1 LINES") or die(mysql_error());
```

And of course no luck. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming this is a scheduled job, why not check the directory for the most recent file that matches your filename template.  Store the name of said file in a variable and then sub the variable into your query.  Check out [`glob()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Comment: I used this approach, as it worked best for what I was attempting. Danke!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it via a shell script or windows cmd file. This assumes you created the file with mysqldump or some program that creates a valid sql script.

You can run dir /B in windows commend to get a directory of files. So do a dir /B > input.txt then use Windows scripting to read the input file and for each line, pipe the file in using the mysql client.

```
@ echo off  set infile= %%1
for /f "eol= tokens=*
delims= usebackq" %%i in  (%infile%)
do (  mysql -u userName --password=pwd < %%i  )
```

It's been a long time since I wrote any windows scripts, but that should give you an idea of an approach.